# How to feed a RDLC report with a custom IEnumerable grouped by

Tags: c#, grouping, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation, igrouping

I want to reuse the same RDLC to display different tables depending on a format field. But my report does not show anything when the data source has the `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Row>>` return type already grouped.

So **if the users picks the format A, the report would display a table grouped by some columns and if the user picks the format B the report would display the table grouped by something else**.

My plan B would be to simply pass the datasource as an Enumerable and then order by in the report itself, but I wanted to have all the logic in the code, not in the RDLC..

I am using custom Dataset to build the report as follows:

```
    public byte[] GetReport(ReportFormat reportFormat)
    {
        MyReportDataSource myReportDataSource = GetMyReportDataSource(reportFormat);

        ReportDataSource dsDetails = GetDetailsDataSource(myReportDataSource);
        ReportDataSource dsRows = GetRowsDataSource(myReportDataSource);

        LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();
        localReport.ReportPath = "pathToMyRdlc.rdlc";
        localReport.DataSources.Add(dsDetails);
        localReport.DataSources.Add(dsRows);

        Warning[] warnings;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;
        string[] streams;

        byte[] reportBytes = localReport.Render("pdf", null, PageCountMode.Actual,
                        out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);

        return reportBytes;
    }

    private MyReportDataSource GetMyReportDataSource(ReportFormat reportFormat)
    {
        MyReportDataSource r = new MyReportDataSource();
        r.ReportFormat = ReportFormat.A;
        //some test rows
        Row row1 = new Row
        {
            Name = "Joe",
            LastName = "Doe",
            Age = 42
        };
        Row row2 = new Row
        {
            Name = "Jane",
            LastName = "Doe",
            Age = 26
        };
        Row row3 = new Row
        {
            Name = "Joe",
            LastName = "Smith",
            Age = 31
        };
        r.AddRow(row1);
        r.AddRow(row2);
        r.AddRow(row3);
        return r;
    }

    private ReportDataSource GetDetailsDataSource(MyReportDataSource myReportDataSource)
    {
        //ReportDataSource only accepts dataTable or IEnumerable, use IEnumerable but with single element as workaround
        List<MyReportDataSource> listSingleItem = new List<MyReportDataSource>();
        listSingleItem.Add(myReportDataSource);

        ReportDataSource detailsDataSource = new ReportDataSource("DSDetails", listSingleItem.AsEnumerable());
        return detailsDataSource;
    }

    private ReportDataSource GetDeclarationRowsDataSource(MyReportDataSource myReportDataSource)
    {
        ReportDataSource rowsDataSource = new ReportDataSource("DSRows", myDataSource.Rows);
        return rowsDataSource;
    }
```

so basically I'm passing to the local report two datasources, one `DSDetails` is for the details (where the specified format is) and the other `DSRows` for an internal Enumerable which has the data I want to display in the table. This would be my custom datasource object

```
public class DeclarationReportDataSource
{
    public ReportFormat ReportFormat { get; set; }

    private decimal _totalAge;
    public decimal TotalAge
    {
        get
        {
            return Math.Round(this._totalAge, 2);
        }
    }
    private List<Row> _Rows = new List<Row>();
    //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    //This is the method that returns an IEnumerable ordered by
    //depending on the format
    //There is no problem to display data if I return an IEnumerable<Row>
    public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Row>> Rows
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.ReportFormat == ReportFormat.A)
            {
                return this._Rows.GroupBy(r => r.Name);
            }
            //else group by different field
            return this._Rows.GroupBy(r => r.LastName);
        }
    }

    public void AddRow(Row row)
    {
        this._Rows.Add(row);
        this._totalAge += row.Age;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty new with RDLC, so any guidance or good article on how to do something similar would be much appreciated. Thanks

**UPDATE** My table in the report is displaying 2 empty rows, so the group by in the code works good but the rows don't display anything. So I suspect I'm missing some concept on how to render grouped rows. I'll keep investigating.